# Centering multiple labels with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is it possible to center these countdown labels using autolayout?

I have a centered view (as pictured in dark blue) with four labels: minuteValue, minuteUnit, secondValue and secondUnit.

When the countdown timer is under 60 seconds the minute labels are hidden. Is it possible to center the timer whatever state it is in; i.e. whether I have 2 or 4 labels?

If no one knows of an autolayout solution I am happy to code it in, but my preference is to do achieve this using autolayout if possible.

[image: View with four labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want them **always** be centered, whether two or four labels. In this case, I would add one contentView for them. So, you receive something like this:

YourBlueView -> ContainerView -> FourLabels

Next, center your containerView in YourBlueView with:

```
yourBlueView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourBlueView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
yourBlueView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourBlueView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Final step, add constraints to your labels in containerView, something like

```
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[firstLabel]|", metrics: nil, views: ["firstLabel": firstLabel]))
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[firstLabel][secondLabel][thirdLabel][fourthLabel]|",options: [.alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["firstLabel": firstLabel,"secondLabel": secondLabel,"thirdLabel": thirdLabel,"fourthLabel": fourthLabel]))
```

Now, when you set your labels width to 0, they will remain in the center.

Another solution, more clear, but requires UIStackView. Put all labels into it, as you're using storyboard, it can be done with button **Embed In Stack**, under your storyboard window, and center this stack view in your blue view. Job is done

Answer (score 1):

Add all your 4 labels in a `UIView` and add the following constrains to the view.

1. Horizontally in Container
2. Vertically in Container

Add constraints to all the labels. Now when you wan't to hide the minutes set the empty text for both the minutes label (`28` label and `mins` label).

Hope it helps. Thanks.